# Show array list as specific list in JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arraylist, push

I have this list:

```
var objData =[{"Id":1,"Title":"T1"},{"Id":3,"Title":"T2"}];
```

Need to show it on 'data', like this:

```
data{
"1":"T1",
"3":"T2"
}
```

How could to make a array list and show it on 'data', Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr =[{"Id":1,"Title":"T1"},{"Id":3,"Title":"T2"}];
const res = arr.reduce((acc,{Id,Title})=>(acc[Id]=Title,acc),{})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var objData =[{"Id":1,"Title":"T1"},{"Id":3,"Title":"T2"}];
var data = {};
objData.forEach(o => data[o.Id] = data.Title)
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Your answer is right, the only problem is title is undefined ```{ 1: undefined,  3: undefined}```

Comment: You can put a check there (ternary `if`) for undefined and either include it in the `data` or put `null`

Comment: Look at this result please https://jsfiddle.net/d6voL3r7/14/ , I believe it's not about checking null data.  Also could we have quotation on this type of code? Look at question please it's not ```{1:``` , it's ```{'1':```